# Can't get the correct result even after using distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the results of the query below:

```
select distinct
       REQ_ID
     , ID
     , MAX(STEP) as step
     , SUBSTRING(p1.NAME,9, len(p1.NAME)) as _index_
     , p2.value as location

from HISTORY h

LEFT JOIN Parameter p1 
on     p1.WP_ID=h.ID
   AND (   (    p1.NAME like 'name_' 
            AND p1.VALUE like h.ID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT ) 
        OR (    p1.NAME like 'name__' 
            AND p1.VALUE like h.ID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT) )

LEFT JOIN Parameter p2 
on     p2.WP_ID=h.ID 
   AND p2.PA_NAME = 'Location' + (SUBSTRING(p1.NAME,9, len(p1.NAME)) ) 

WHERE h.ROLE = 'rock'

GROUP BY REQ_ID, ID, step, p1.name, p2.value
```

The problem is that the query is returning more than 1 results (in my case there are 6) and the `MAX(STEP)` value is not returning the max, I can see values like 0,1,3,0,1,2
Is there a way to get only the result with the `max(step)`? the `step` field is `varchar(1)`

Comment: Just a side note. Using `max(step)` doesn't work if you group by `step`. Since each distinct step is a new group, there is only one distinct value for `step` in that group, so `max(step)` is always that one `step`. Maybe SQL Server handles the aliasing differently (since you also use `step` as an alias for `max(step)`, but I think this might be where you go wrong. To prevent confusion, I would choose a different alias, like `max_step`.

Comment: Common and good advice:  Show us some example input data and the results you would want from that input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with `first record in a group`, the often simplest approach is to use `ROW_NUMBER()`.  Without knowing more about your schema and data, I can say that the following query will work, but it may be possible to simplifiy it further...

```
WITH
  sequenced_data AS
(
  SELECT
    REQ_ID,
    ID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY req_id, id ORDER BY step DESC) AS sequence_id,
    STEP,
    SUBSTRING(p1.NAME,9, len(p1.NAME)) as _index_,
    p2.value as location
  FROM
    HISTORY    h
  LEFT JOIN
    Parameter  p1
      ON  p1.WP_ID = h.ID
      AND (   (p1.NAME like 'name_' AND p1.VALUE  like h.ID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT ) 
           OR (p1.NAME like 'name__' AND p1.VALUE  like h.ID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT)
          )
  LEFT JOIN
    Parameter  p2
      ON  p2.WP_ID = h.ID
      AND p2.PA_NAME = 'Location' + (SUBSTRING(p1.NAME,9, len(p1.NAME)) ) 
  WHERE
    h.ROLE = 'rock'
  GROUP BY
    REQ_ID,
    ID,
    STEP,
    SUBSTRING(p1.NAME,9, len(p1.NAME)),
    p2.value
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sequenced_data
WHERE
  sequence_id = 1
```

This will give only one row per `req_id, id` combination, and will always pick the row with the highest `step` value.

*NOTE:* I don't know if the `GROUP BY` is still needed.  I left it in simply because you had it.

Answer (score 0):

To get only one record with the highest step, use

```
SELECT TOP(1)
......
......
ORDER BY step desc
```

Comment: What if the OP really does need multiple rows *(one row for each `REQ_ID,ID` for example)*?

Comment: In that case, OP would just need to remove `step` from the `GROUP BY` clause, like I had posted before and Parado described as well. After re-reading the question I figured that this would be the better answer, but maybe I understood it wrong after all.

Comment: That only works if *(for example)* the `p2.value` is the same for all `step` values. If each `step` has a different `p2.value`, but the op only wants the row with the highest `step`, such a change doesn't work either. *[It requires a join on to a sub query, where the sub query finds the `MAX(step)`, or the use of something like `ROW_NUMBER()` to find the row with the max `step` value.]*

Comment: It's just a matter of interpretation of the question. You don't have to convince me why  that answer would be wrong, because I'm not even sure it answers the question. That's why I deleted that answer in the first place. I would say your answer is wrong, since it returns a row *per group* while the OP just asks for "one row". Maybe it would be best if we just close-vote the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (remove step from group by):

```
select REQ_ID,ID,MAX(STEP) as step,SUBSTRING(p1.NAME,9, len(p1.NAME)) as _index_,
p2.value as location
from HISTORY h
LEFT JOIN Parameter p1 on p1.WP_ID  =h.ID  AND 
( (p1.NAME like 'name_' AND p1.VALUE  like h.ID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT ) 
OR (p1.NAME like 'name__' AND p1.VALUE  like h.ID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT) )
LEFT JOIN Parameter p2 on p2.WP_ID=h.ID AND p2.PA_NAME = 'Location' + (SUBSTRING(p1.NAME,9, len(p1.NAME)) ) 
WHERE h.ROLE = 'rock'
GROUP BY REQ_ID,ID, p1.name, p2.value
```

or

remove `step` and  add `SUBSTRING(p1.NAME,9, len(p1.NAME))` to group by:

```
select REQ_ID,ID,MAX(STEP) as step,SUBSTRING(p1.NAME,9, len(p1.NAME)) as _index_,
p2.value as location
from HISTORY h
LEFT JOIN Parameter p1 on p1.WP_ID  =h.ID  AND 
( (p1.NAME like 'name_' AND p1.VALUE  like h.ID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT ) 
OR (p1.NAME like 'name__' AND p1.VALUE  like h.ID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT) )
LEFT JOIN Parameter p2 on p2.WP_ID=h.ID AND p2.PA_NAME = 'Location' + (SUBSTRING(p1.NAME,9, len(p1.NAME)) ) 
WHERE h.ROLE = 'rock'
GROUP BY REQ_ID,ID, SUBSTRING(p1.NAME,9, len(p1.NAME)),p2.value
```

Comment: This assumes that `p2.value` is the same for every `step`.  If each `step` relates to a different `p2.value`, this won't work.

Comment: but it shows 0 (zero) at the `max(step)` even when the max is 3

Comment: Try to remove `WHERE h.ROLE = 'rock'`

Comment: But I need it to be `rock` as there are also records for `metal`

Comment: Where is column `step`? In which table ?

Comment: Yes, I expected this. Are you sure in table `history` there is a row `where step = 3 and ROLE = 'rock'` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is `step=3` that's why I'm trying to get the `max(step)` - There are 3 steps

Comment: Try to run this query `select * from history where step = '3' and ROLE = 'rock'` then you will see.